# Django Best method to create different users

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am creating a School Management System where there should be 3 types of users (Student, Teacher, Authorities). Can anyone please help me in giving me a direction to proceed since I'm stuck in this.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you thought about your data model? Do the different types of users need different data? Could it be possible that an user is both a Student and a Teacher in some cases?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in various ways. The simplest one is creating 3 Models representing Student, Teacher, Authorities with One to One Relationship with Django User Model. If you're experienced enough you can use the AbstractUser interface(abstract class) and extend it to create 3 models for three different types of users.
Examples:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models


class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # other fields


# or
class UserProfile(AbstractUser):
    phone = models.IntegerField(max_length=10, null=True)
    # other fields
    # please read docs before working with this.
```

[AbstractUser Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project)